# How can I remotely access Ubuntu 16.04 desktop on Jetson TX1?

Tags: arm, remote-access, ubuntu-16.04

How can I remotely access Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, installed on an Jetson TX1 (Armhf arch) from another Ubuntu machine?
So, both of the machines have internet, i.e. I could ping google.com in Jetson TX1's terminal, however, I can not ping the Jetson TX1 from the other Ubuntu machine. I think Jetson TX1 is connected to a network which does not allow access outside the local network, and I can not also forward respective ports to enable access.
After googling a bit about it, I found out that using teamviewer is the easiest way to enable remote access but it does not support armhf architecture.
Is there an easy way to install Teamviewer like packages or apps on Jetson TX1 and be able to access it outside this local network over internet?
Habib

Answer (score -2):

To access other machine 
Both the machine should have Teamviewer installed in it
For ubuntu first open the terminal and write down these command to install it

1. Grab the TeamViewer debfile:
   **wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb**
2. Install the downloaded DEB file:
   **sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb**
3. If DPKG throws any errors, fix any dependency issues to make sure          everything works fine:
   **sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install**

Now in terminal write **teamviewer**
the window for teamviewer opens up and it generate a particular id and password for every machine 
If you want to access other machine then mention the id and password for that machine in the form and enter **Ok.**
You have entered into other person machine.

Comment: This is for x86 machines, and the Jetson TX1 is not of that architecture.